# How to LEFT OUTER JOIN on specific column values in HIVEQL?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

When I run the following HiveQL code I get the error:
    Execute error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:2112 Invalid table alias or 
       column reference 'T3'

```
    SELECT *        
    FROM CC_CLAIM_EXT T1
    INNER JOIN CC_EXPOSURE_EXT T2 ON (T1.ID = T2.CLAIMID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_POLICY_EXT T3 ON (T1.POLICYID = T3.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_COVERAGE_EXT T4 ON (T2.COVERAGEID = T4.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_TRANSACTION_EXT T5 ON (T2.ID = T5.EXPOSUREID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_TRANSACTIONSET_EXT T6 ON (T5.TRANSACTIONSETID = T6.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_TRANSACTIONLINEITEM_EXT T7 ON (T5.ID = T7.TRANSACTIONID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_RISKUNIT_EXT T12 ON (T4.RISKUNITID = T12.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_CLASSCODE_EXT T13 ON (T12.CLASSCODEID = T13.ID)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TT12.CLAIMID
                            ,CASE WHEN COUNT(TT13.PRIMARYBODYPART) > 1 THEN 10010 ELSE MAX(TT13.PRIMARYBODYPART) END AS PRIMARYBODYPART
                            ,CASE WHEN COUNT(TT13.DETAILEDBODYPART) > 1 THEN 10010 ELSE MAX(TT13.DETAILEDBODYPART) END AS DETAILEDBODYPART
                    FROM CC_INCIDENT_EXT TT12
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_BODYPART_EXT TT13 ON (TT12.ID = TT13.INCIDENTID)
                    GROUP BY TT12.CLAIMID) T14 
    ON (T1.ID = T14.CLAIMID AND T3.POLICYTYPE IN(10022,10023))

    WHERE T1.STATE IN(2,3)
        AND T2.STATE IN(2,3)
        AND T6.APPROVALSTATUS = 1
        AND T7.RETIRED = 0

    ORDER BY CLAIMNUMBER
        ,EXPOSUREID
        ,TRANSACTIONID
```

I've narrowed it down to the line:

```
    ON (T1.ID = T14.CLAIMID AND T3.POLICYTYPE IN(10022,10023))
```

If I delete:

```
    AND T3.POLICYTYPE IN(10022,10023)
```

The code runs fine. Is there a better way to limit this join in HiveQL?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you put a reference on the left join between T1 and T14 BUT you put T3 on the condition. To limit your query to your specified T3.policy_id, you should put in along the line where you left join T1 and T3. See below in line 4:

```
SELECT *        
    FROM CC_CLAIM_EXT T1
    INNER JOIN CC_EXPOSURE_EXT T2 ON (T1.ID = T2.CLAIMID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_POLICY_EXT T3 ON (T1.POLICYID = T3.ID AND T3.POLICYTYPE IN(10022,10023))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_COVERAGE_EXT T4 ON (T2.COVERAGEID = T4.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_TRANSACTION_EXT T5 ON (T2.ID = T5.EXPOSUREID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_TRANSACTIONSET_EXT T6 ON (T5.TRANSACTIONSETID = T6.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_TRANSACTIONLINEITEM_EXT T7 ON (T5.ID = T7.TRANSACTIONID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_RISKUNIT_EXT T12 ON (T4.RISKUNITID = T12.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_CLASSCODE_EXT T13 ON (T12.CLASSCODEID = T13.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TT12.CLAIMID
                            ,CASE WHEN COUNT(TT13.PRIMARYBODYPART) > 1 THEN 10010 ELSE MAX(TT13.PRIMARYBODYPART) END AS PRIMARYBODYPART
                            ,CASE WHEN COUNT(TT13.DETAILEDBODYPART) > 1 THEN 10010 ELSE MAX(TT13.DETAILEDBODYPART) END AS DETAILEDBODYPART
                    FROM CC_INCIDENT_EXT TT12
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC_BODYPART_EXT TT13 ON (TT12.ID = TT13.INCIDENTID)
                    GROUP BY TT12.CLAIMID) T14 
    ON T1.ID = T14.CLAIMID
    WHERE T1.STATE IN(2,3)
        AND T2.STATE IN(2,3)
        AND T6.APPROVALSTATUS = 1
        AND T7.RETIRED = 0
    ORDER BY CLAIMNUMBER
        ,EXPOSUREID
        ,TRANSACTIONID
```